# Beta regression and post hoc test correct linear connectors?

Tags: r, regression, lsmeans, beta-regression

I am trying to run a beta regression on my percent data which can be found [here](https://github.com/kotoniitami/Data/blob/main/MyData.xlsx?raw=true).

My research question: How is percent cover changing in each transect over each event? Beta regression was choosen based on the beta distribution and repeated measures.

[image: This graph shows all raw data points for each transect over the years with a lm regression line.]

My Code:

```
#Run Model
library(betareg)
model = betareg(Percent ~ Transect+Event|Event,data = data3)

#Pairwise Comaparison Post Hoc
library(emmeans)
a<-summary(emmeans(model, pairwise ~ Event|Transect))

#Pull out Significant Values
a1<-a[["contrasts"]]

a2<-a1 %>%
  filter(p.value<.05)
```

I am new to beta regression and am not sure if I am using the correct linear connector (Transect+Event|Event) in the model.

I am getting significant p-values between two major areas that are expected between event 2 and 6 which can be seen in this [Interaction map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TwCU.png), but there seems to be some inconsistencies.

My questions:

1. Am I using the betareg and emmeans functions correctly?
2. Is this the correct linear connector in the model and post hoc analysis for this problem?

Comment: I find the very last step irritating. I hope you are looking at all of the results.

Comment: @RussLength I am looking at all the results as well. It's the reason I suspect something might be wrong, but can't figure out what.